# Does YouTube meet WCAG 2.1 standards regarding close captions?

Tags: youtube-api, wcag, closed-captions

We upload our board meetings to YouTube for library members to watch at their convenience. We need to know if the close captions provided meet WCAG 2.1 standards.

I have been researching WCAG 2.1 standards and am measuring our website against them. We have many YouTube links on our site and I am attempting to double check how effectively we are meeting the close caption standards described at: https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G87.html

Comment: Unfortunately, [WCAG 1.2.2](https://w3c.github.io/wcag/guidelines/22/#captions-prerecorded) just says captions are required for pre-recorded content but doesn't say how **accurate** they have to be. Auto-generated captions are "ok", but not great. There are always mistakes but you have to watch them to see if those mistakes are minor or if they convey very inaccurate information. I recommend reading this article on [best practices for captions](https://meryl.net/why-captioned-videos-are-important/).